# my code is not showing is the terminal and there is no error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was trying to run a code in vs code but the code didn't run and there is no error showing in the terminal. I made a new file and then tried to run a "Hello World!" but the code didn't run too. I uninstalled and re-installed vs code (three times) but that didn't work.

And when I say that there is no error showing I mean it. whenever I run the code nothing happens and vs code doesn't even give a hint or a sign that the code got executed or not.

Comment: Did you forget the `print` in `print("hello world")`? Please include the exact code you're running in the question as text.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: maybe first run it normally in console/terminal `python script.py` without using `vs code`

Comment: you could also start `vs code` in console/terminal to see if it doesn't generate own errors when you run it. Also I'm not sure if `vs code` doesn't need to install `extension` to work with `Python`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you should understand that vscode is a lightweight editing
   tool. If you want to run python files, first make sure you have
   installed python correctly. You can enter command `python --version`
   in the terminal to confirm it.

[image]

2. Then, please install python extension in the vscode extension store.

[image]

3. Then use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select
   Interpreter" to choose the python interpreter.

[image]

4. Finally, creat ***.py** file and run it.

Read [this docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) for more details which can help you get started faster.